# Is this category complete or Cauchy complete?

Tags: category-theory

Define a category as follows:  the objects are categories and the arrows are embeddings (full and faithful functors).  Is this category Cauchy complete or complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that every idempotent splits in your category: if $e:C\to C$ is idempotent and fully faithful, let $B$ be the full subcategory of $C$ spanned by the objects in the image of $C$.  Then the inclusion $B\to C$ is fully faithful, and $e$ factors fully faithfully through this inclusion, giving a splitting of $e$.

However, your category is not complete, because it does not have products.  For instance, let $C$ be the discrete category with two objects $a$ and $b$.  Suppose you have a product $P=C\times C$, with projection functors $p_0,p_1:P\to C$.  There are two fully faithful functors $C\to C$, namely the identity $1$ and the functor $f$ which swaps $a$ and $b$.  There is a unique fully faithful functor $g:C\to P$ such that $p_0g=p_1g=1$, and also a unique fully faithful functor $h:C\to P$ such that $p_0h=1$ and $p_1h=f$.  Since the $p_i$ are fully faithful, $p_0g=p_0h=1$ implies $g(a)\cong h(a)$ and $g(b)\cong h(b)$ in $P$.  But $p_1g=1$ and $p_1h=f$ implies $g(a)\cong h(b)$ and $g(b)\cong h(a)$.  This implies $g(a)\cong g(b)$, contradicting that $g$ should be fully faithful.